# How to get the focus of the elements in javascript using keyarrows

Tags: javascript, html, css

My html contains list of elements. I want to use the arrow keys to select the elements.

Here is my Code: `[http://jsfiddle.net/T8S7c/]`

What I want is on preesing the keys the focus needs to be in the selected element like hover effects.( For example if I press the down key for the first time Ambaji has to be in focus)

I know the code of the key event but i dont know how to get the focus on the keypress.

Can anyone help me in this

Comment: yes jquery is allowed

Comment: why not use tabindex ?

Comment: Sorry, I am new to javascript. Can you explain me how to use tab index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My strategy for solving this would be to specify an order of focus through an array of the links, as well as having some variable specifying which link should be in focus.

```
var order = new Array("l1", "l2", "l3", "l4");
var current = -1;

function updateCurrent(inc) {
    current = (current + inc) % order.length;
    current = Math.max(current, 0);
}

document.onkeydown = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;

    switch (evt.keyCode) {
        case 38:
            updateCurrent(-1);
            document.getElementById(order[current]).focus();
            break;
        case 40:
            updateCurrent(1);
            document.getElementById(order[current]).focus();
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks Mike. It is working but one small help  when i press the down key for the first time it is focussing the second element

Comment: Try now (initial `current` is set to `-1`).

Comment: one more help Mike. On clicking the enter button i want to show the contents related to that element. Where to check that condition for enter key I tried this code: http://jsfiddle.net/daEfL/ but it is not coming @Mikke

Answer (score 1):

Updated your script. Have a look at this. Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/T8S7c/6/

```
var myLinks = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
var myLinksIndex = 0;
myLinks[myLinksIndex].focus();
document.onkeydown = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    switch (evt.keyCode) {
        case 38: // Up arrow
            if(myLinksIndex > 0){myLinks[-- myLinksIndex].focus();}
            break;
        case 40:// Down arrow
           if(myLinksIndex < myLinks.length){myLinks[++ myLinksIndex].focus();}
            break;
    }
};
```